# In swagger UI how to expand and scrolling down to operation on clicking link in description of the page

Tags: markdown, swagger-ui

I am using swashbuckle swagger with asp.net MVC web API(on .net framework) and have a custom index.html for API documentation. In the introduction description section I have a html markdown text

```
Before performing any activity with the API, the caller must first Authenticate using the [Login](#!/Security/Login_0)
```

I have also set deeplink property in index.html as below

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            url: swashbuckleConfig.rootUrl + "/" + swashbuckleConfig.discoveryPaths[0],
            dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
            deepLinking: true,
```

The above block of markdown code renders "Login" text as a hyperlink. When I click on it users are taken to the login method under security controller but the hyperlink opens in a new tab.

How can I make the hyperlink scroll down and open the Login operation on the same tab/page?

Comment: This is a known issue with Markdown links in Swagger UI. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3473